# Search in MVC 4 and repeat in the same view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to place a search bar in the main index view so that i can search for specific clients. I'll make one search for a name and it works fine, but if I try to search again I get..

> **Server Error in '/' Application.** The resource cannot be found.
>
> > Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of
> >     its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
> >     temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
> >     sure that it is spelled correctly.
> >
> > Requested URL: /Client/Client/Index

I want to be able to repeat searching and go back to a main index as well.

**Controller class**

```
public class ClientController : Controller
{
    private VolumeV2Context db = new VolumeV2Context();

    //
    // GET: /Client/

    public ActionResult Index(string SearchParam)
    {
        if (SearchParam == null)
        {
              //just load the main index 
            return View(db.Clients.Take(25).ToList());
        }
        else
        {
             //search for the client name
            var clients = db.Clients.Where(c => c.FirstName.Contains(SearchParam) || c.LastName.Contains(SearchParam)).Take(10).ToList();
            return View(clients);

        }
    }
```

**Index View**
I use a partial view here as well for each client line by line. I thought it would make it easier for me

```
@model IEnumerable<VolumeV2.Models.Clients>


@{  
ViewBag.Title = "Index";

}

<h2>Index</h2>

<form action="Client/Index" method="get" >
<input type="text" name="SearchParam" />
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
<table class="client" id ="results">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmailList)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.HairType)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>


   @foreach( var item in Model){

 @Html.Partial("SearchedClients",item)

}
           </table>
</form>
```

**Partial View**

```
@model VolumeV2.Models.Clients


<tr >
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.EmailList)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.HairType)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = Model.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = Model.Id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Address", "GetAddress", new { id = Model.Id })

    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You have one return as `return View("index","Client",clients)` and the other as `return View("Index","client", ... )` - are they copy pasted from your code? If so, _index_ probably shouldn't have a small _i_ and _client_ shouldn't have a small _c_. Even better, you don't actually need to specify them as the `View` you're returning has the same name as your action, so all you need is `return View(clients)`

Comment: Duly noted, I've made the changes and I'm getting a new error now. The Url path changes when I try to make a second search. I'll update the post now to show my new error.

Answer (score 0):

Change the form action from "/Client/Index" to "../Client/Index"

Comment: Glad you got sorted. So that you don't get confused in future, you can use MVC form helpers to sort out the paths -  `@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Index", FormMethod.Get })) { // form stuff here }` will generate the correct URL from wherever your `View` is. You can also mark your own answer as correct :)